# Kinect DiscreteGestureResult Confidence value algorithm

Tags: c#

I'm decompiling the DiscreteGestureResult class

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.visualgesturebuilder.discretegestureresult.confidence.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

within the Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder library using ReSharper in order to understand how the "Confidence" property value is calculated.

Here is the decompiled code:

[image]

I realise you can't expect to have 100% of the source code merely through decompilation of libraries, but unfortunately no indication is given into the underlying calculation of the Confidence value. Is there any way I can dig further into this property to get at more specific data?